# Lists of labelled vectors, how to output a list of tuples which sum to zero

Tags: list-manipulation, associations

list = {{1, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 1}, {-1, 1, 0}, {1, -1,  0}, {-1, -1, 0}, {-1, 0, 1},
{1, 0,-1}, {-1, 0, -1}, {0, -1, 1}, {0, 1, -1}, {0, -1, -1}};

list2 = {{2, 0, 0}, {0, 2, 0}, {0, 0, 2}, {-2, 0, 0}, {0, -2, 0}, {0, 0, -2}}

@Ulrich Neumann  gave the following algorithm which finds the all zero sums (duplication is allowed) where "a" vectors are selected from list and "b" vectors from list2.

`slist = Tuples[list, {a}]; listb = Tuples[list2, {b}] Table[{li, Select[slist, Total[#] == -Total[li] &]}, {li, listb}]`

For instance, when a=2, and b=1, one part of the result  which the above code gives:{{{2, 0, 0}}, {{{-1, 1, 0}, {-1, -1, 0}}, {{-1, -1, 0}, {-1, 1, 0}}, {{-1, 0, 1}, {-1, 0, -1}}, {{-1, 0, -1}, {-1, 0, 1}}}}

My problem is listing the results .I want to assign letters to each vectors in the list and list2,   let list = {a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8, a9, a10, a11, a12}; where a1={1, 1, 0}, a2={1, 0, 1}, a3={0, 1, 1}, a4={-1, 1, 0}, a5={1, -1, 0}, a6={-1, -1, 0},a7= {-1,0,1}, a8= {1,0,-1}, a9= {-1,0,-1}, a10={0,-1,1},  a11={0,1,-1},  a12={0,-1,-1},

and list2={b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6} where b1={2, 0, 0}, b2={0, 2, 0}, b3={0, 0, 2}, b4={-2, 0, 0}, b5={0, -2, 0}, b6={0, 0, -2}.

I want to have the results in the associated form.  So for instance, reconsider  the specific part of result: {{{2, 0, 0}}, {{{-1, 1, 0}, {-1, -1, 0}}, {{-1, -1, 0}, {-1, 1, 0}}, {{-1, 0, 1}, {-1, 0, -1}}, {{-1, 0, -1}, {-1, 0, 1}}}}.
It needs to be in the form: {{b1}, {{a4, a6}, {a6, a4}, {a7, a9}, {a9, a7}}}  and I want the whole output to be in terms of letters rather than explicit vectors.   How can we manage this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend that you use indexed variables

```
Clear["Global`*"]

Format[a[n_]] := Subscript[a, n];
Format[b[n_]] := Subscript[b, n];

list[1] = {{1, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 1}, {-1, 1, 0}, {1, -1, 0}, {-1, -1, 
    0}, {-1, 0, 1}, {1, 0, -1}, {-1, 0, -1}, {0, -1, 1}, {0, 
    1, -1}, {0, -1, -1}};

list[2] = {{2, 0, 0}, {0, 2, 0}, {0, 0, 2}, {-2, 0, 0}, {0, -2, 0}, {0, 
    0, -2}};
```

Create a replacement [`Rule`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rule.html) for each list element

```
(repl[#] = 
    Thread[list[#] ->
      Array[{a, b}[[#]], Length[list[#]]]]) & /@ {1, 2}
```

[image]

```
sol[m_Integer?Positive, n_Integer?Positive] :=
 Module[{
   lista = Tuples[list[1], {m}],
   listb = Tuples[list[2], {n}]},
   Table[
   {li /. repl[2], Select[lista, Total[#] == -Total[li] &] /. repl[1]},
   {li, listb}]]

sol[2, 1]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the code @Bob Hanlon  I would like to reduce the list which we get as a result. I would like to drop  the results which contains 2   indexed variables together. For example,  consider your example sol[2,1]. I would like to drop the answers which contains a4 and a6 together in the result. So in this case {a4,a6} and {a6,a4} will be eliminated or let consider sol[2,2] I would like the drop the results  which contains b1 and b4 together.  I know we will use the commands: drop or select commands but I couldnt set up. How can we manage this? –

Comment: To ask a new question post a new question. In the new question clarify want you want. For example, when you say "drop the results" do you mean drop the entire entry for `b[1]` or just its elements that contain both `a[4]` and `a[6]`? This is generally clarified by showing one or more examples of specific output expected for given inputs.

Comment: many thanks for your help so far @Bob Hanlon.  My question is about a small update about the code that you wrote.   The code does not solve the cases when   "m is positive integer but n is zero. For instance, it does not solve  sol[3, 0] which has at least  has a solution: a[1]+a[7]+a[12]={0,0,0}.  I tried to change "Positive" with "NonNegative" in the code, but it did not work. Do you have any advise. If needed I may ask this in a new question. Many thanks before hand.

Comment: Change definition of `sol` to `sol[m_Integer?Positive, n_Integer?NonNegative] := Module[{lista = Tuples[list[1], {m}], listb = Tuples[list[2], {n}]}, Table[{li /. repl[2], Select[lista, Total[#] == If[li === {}, Table[0, {Length[#[[1]]]}], -Total[li]] &] /. repl[1]}, {li, listb}]]`